# XIB subviews are not visible

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I load my project from git and now can not see xib subviews. But if I run project in simulator, subviews are visible and works well.
Does somebody know a reason?

[image: empty xib]

Comment: What are their height and width? Are they `(0,0)`

Comment: @InderKumarRathore No, for example for Image View they are `(240, 240)`

Comment: can you send me the link of xib via dropbox or anything

Comment: @InderKumarRathore It is here [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sd0nid8ivyuv5iw/FWPreviewCell.xib?dl=0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using size classes and you have it set to a class where the views aren't installed (which is why they're all dimmed).

Tap on a view and the inspector will tell you which size classes it's installed for. Change the display in Xcode to show that size class, or update the setting so the views are installed in all size classes.

Comment: For hours I've been looking for an answer to this problem. Hours of moving around views, switching settings, adding IBOutlet-enabled subviews manually to their owner classes. And all because the size class was set to "Regular" on the xib views, instead of "Any" ... Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

The views are added on compact width and any height, and you're viewing your xib in any width and any height

[image]